# How to use the latest version of python in emacs?

Tags: python-2.7, emacs

I have installed python 2.7.8 in Cygwin and python 2.7.9 on my drive (`C:/Python27/python.exe`).

My question is: whenever I do `M-x python2.7` in emacs, I always end up using the python 2.7.8 in Cygwin and this is not what I want. I want to be able to use the latest python 2.7.9 on my drive.

I tried the following but it did not give me what I want:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'load-path "C:/Users/mynameis/.emacs.d/python-mode.el-6.1.3")
(setq py-install-directory "C:/Users/mynameis/.emacs.d/python-mode.el-6.1.3")
(require 'python-mode)
```

How can I use Python2.7.9 in emacs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options depending of needs and circumstances: For example customize `py-shell-name` with full path/to/executable.

In case a certain version is needed onyl occasionally, edit python2.7 command giving full path/to/exe as argument - resp. install specific python2.7.8 and  python2.7.9 commands.

For example load this after python-mode.el is loaded:

```
(defun python2.7.9 (&optional argprompt)
  "Start an Python2.7.9 interpreter.

Optional \\[universal-argument] prompts for path to the interpreter. "
  (interactive "p")
  (py-shell argprompt nil "python2.7.9"))
```

However, form above will work only, if python[VERSION] is in the path.

To open a shell which is not in path, write

```
(defun python2.7.9 (&optional argprompt)
  "Start an Python2.7.9 interpreter.

Optional \\[universal-argument] prompts for path to the interpreter. "
  (interactive "p")
  (py-shell argprompt nil"PATH/TO/python2.7.9"))
```

Comment: Can you write some emacs lisp code to elaborate on your answer please ? Because from your answers, the only information I get out of it is that I need to set `(setq py-shell-name "C:/Python27/python.exe")` . What else do I need ? The main problem is that when I do `M-x Python27`, it brings me to the python 2.7.8 that I installed using Cygwin. And this is not really something that I want. I want to be able to use the Python 2.7.9 that I installed on my C drive not the old version in Cygwin.

Comment: @mynameisJEFF Edited. Setting py-shell-name looks okay but doesn't tell which sub-version it calls byond 2.7